# AWS architecture for a WordPress installation and React Native

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-ec2

I have a simple yet complex problem in my design and need some help.

I want to implement a wordpress instance on my AWS EC2 instance with the following architecture:

AWS architecture for a WP site on AWS

[image]

So i agree with the architecture, but i have a React Native app that gets the data from the site via the WP-API, but i am unsure on how to have my and the desired architecture on AWS

Do i use amazon API gateway and create a proxy that meets the WP-API?
or am i over thinking the idea and the site will run correctly with the React Native app getting data from the site?

I assume, the proxy route - i assume the app users sends the request through to the Site using the WP-API, but with the new architecture, they would still use the wp-api but it meets the proxy and that takes over but i am unsure if this will affect the way the app users use the app, like using AWS will be better but if i only rely on the WP-API, as that would shoot down the performance?

i hope im making sense guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will gain anything from getting API Gateway involved in that setup. I would simply deploy it using that architecture, and let the React Native apps talk to the same servers that serve the Wordpress site. I.e. simply let the Wordpress Instances serve the WP-API also.

Since you already have autoscaling, there is no drawback to using those, and API Gateway can be rather complex to set up, and doesn't really get you anything you need in this scenario.